# c++ template member function that changes parameters depending on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

---Edit for more context---

Lets say I have a class called TempClass. As the name suggests its a template class. It has a bunch of stuff that doesnt really matter to this question, but the interesting stuff is a member function called `addTo` and a member variable that is a unordered_map object. Lets call it `inserted`. Everything in `inserted` was put in there using `addTo`. What `addTo` should do is make some object that is then inserted into the collection at the given key. The inserted instance should be created inside of the function rather than passed to it.

```
addTo(KeyType key, ...) // im looking for what I should put at ...
```

Basically I am stuck at everything after key. I need a way I can specify the data for the newly created instance without having to worry about the objects lifetime or complicate things with calls to std::make_xxx(shared, unique etc).

Here is how I want it to be called

```
TempClass<std::string> stringClass();
stringClass.addTo(whereToAddIt, "This was selected because of std::string");
TempClass<Vector3f> vectorClass();
vectorClass.addTo(someOtherLocation, 12.0f,12.0f,3.0f); //adds a vec(12.0f,12.0f,3.0f)
```

I have seen this done this way and if this is good practice in general id love to implement it this way.

What I have tried:

- Passing a pointer to the function 
  ------> Works but is stupid. It required me to pay attention to deleting the object
- Passing a temporary object and copying it before inserting
  ------> Works but I dislike having to copy the object just to delete it. It seems redunant and is not optimal for my specific application.

I have seen this done before, but I cant remember where (trust me I have tried to remember this, since if I could I could just look it up myself). Please explain to me in detail how to do this and how it works.

Please help me figure this out!

Comment: What are those `whereToAddIt`, `someOtherLocation` ? If they are "irrelevant", then you even don't need to mention class template `TempClass`.

Comment: @liliscent Well they are irrelevant for the core concept of the thing I am looking for I guess. But they arent irrelevant if you want to understand what I am doing. I guess I need to add some context

Comment: @liliscent I changed the entire question so that everything has more relevance and that more context is provided.

Comment: If you pass constructor variables to create an object the copy-delete will almost definitely be elided. If this is only for performance its most likely not an issue. 



Why isn't your method:

`template<class... params> void addTo(KeyType key, params...)`

not 

`template<class location, class... params> addTo<location>(params... p)`

**edit if you need key/value pairs I'll show a way how to make a stack_array though I'm not 100% sure its what you are asking

Comment: `TempClass<std::string> stringClass();` is a function declaration (vexing parse), you should use `TempClass<std::string> stringClass{};` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can use overloads, and then enable a certain overload when your templated type is a certain type</strike>

```
#include <type_traits> //for enable_if and is_same

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    template<typename = std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T, std::string>>>
    void someMember(string param1, int param2);
    template<typename = std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T, Vector3f>>>
    void someMember(string param1, int param2, int param3);
};
```

This will select the first overload is T is std:string, and the second overload if T is a Vector3f.

Edit: Looking at your edited question, a much better approach would be to just pass an instance of T to your addTo function. Like:

```
void addTo(std::string key, T const& value);
```

EDIT2: I think I finally know what you actually want. You need to use variadic templates and perfect forwarding. This might seem confusing, so I will give you code:

```
template<typename KeyType, typename... Args>
void addTo(KeyType key, Args&&... args)
{
   //now construct the new element with:
   T elem(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

You will need to include the utility header. For more information on variadic templates see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: Unfortunately this is undesireable since I gave vector and string as mere examples. The actual types will be unknown and can be virtually anything from a int to a complex class.

Comment: I saw that in your edited question, but when writing this answer your question was still in it's old state. I have an updated answer for you that is much simpler to use. Also, here you don't really have to worry about object lifetime, as you stated in your question

Comment: Well as I said I dont want to create a temporary object in order for it to be copied into the collection, since I cant really just store a reference in the collection. Id much rather have a nice way to just pass the parameters and instantiate the instance once in the function itself. I dont know if/how thats possible but I have seen it before :/

Comment: I have updated my answer again, and this time I think it will actually help. Note that you will also need a C++11 compatible compiler to compile this, but you most likely have that.

Comment: I managed to implement it into my code. Thanks for the really quick answer :) It works great! My program is crashing right now but for different reasons, which are easy to fix. However the constructors are getting thier data perfectly :) Im marking this answer as correct since you were the first one to put it up and also the most interactive ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use variadic template and perfect forwarding to emplace a k/v pair:

```
template<class K, class V>
struct foo {
    template<class... Args>
    void addTo(K k, Args&&... args) {
        mp.emplace(
                std::piecewise_construct, 
                std::forward_as_tuple(k),
                std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
                );
    }
    std::unordered_map<K, V> mp;
};
```

Comment: Nice, never seen `std::piecewise_construct` before.